# Select multiple columns inside table and retrieve value from jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been looking hours and hours but I cannot find a solution to my problem.. I have literally searched everywhere on StackOverflow....

Case: I got a HTML table with many different columns. I want to select multiple columns inside my table and make them retrieve values from jquery.

[image]

I do not want to achieve the result above, but I want to achieve result below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: A better example: `http://jsfiddle.net/jrthib/HVw7E/2`
As you can see here, when you select a column, you select multiple columns (4 columns). This is exactly the result I want to achieve, but the only difference is that I also want to retrieve values from jquery at the same time.

Comment: Retrieve values of what?Values of the column that the user clicked?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Here is the value I want to retrieve

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var connectToServer = 'ws://84.200.4.68:'
  connect(connectToServer + 443,true);
   $('#choosemode').on('change', function() {
     var mode = $("#choosemode").val()
     switch (mode) {
    case 'world_1':
     connect(connectToServer + 443,true);
     break;
    case 'world_2':
     connect(connectToServer + 5422,true);
     break;
    case 'world_3':
     connect(connectToServer + 5423,true);
     break;
    }
   });
   
 })  
 </script>

Comment: `<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var connectToServer = 'ws://84.200.4.68:'
  connect(connectToServer + 443,true);
   $('#choosemode').on('change', function() {
     var mode = $("#choosemode").val()
     switch (mode) {
    case 'world_1':
     connect(connectToServer + 443,true);
     break;
    case 'world_2':
     connect(connectToServer + 5422,true);
     break;
    case 'world_3':
     connect(connectToServer + 5423,true);
     break;
    }
   });
   
 })  
 </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Well that's really simple.I took the jsfiddle which you provided in the comment and made changes to it to access the column values in the row that was clicked by the user and display the results in an alert box. I hope it helps you:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        tr.highlighted td {
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $('#data tr').click(function (e) {
                $('#data tr').removeClass('highlighted');
                $(this).addClass('highlighted');

                var columns = $(this).children();

                var name = $(columns[0]).text();
                var surname = $(columns[1]).text();
                var age = $(columns[2]).text();
                var dob = $(columns[3]).text();

                var clickedRow = "Name - " + name + ".Surname - " + surname + ".Age - " + age;

                alert(clickedRow);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500" id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td>User Name 1</td>
            <td>User Surname 1</td>
            <td>User Age 1</td>
            <td>User DOB 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name 2</td>
            <td>User Surname 2</td>
            <td>User Age 2</td>
            <td>User DOB 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Look here: http://prntscr.com/bobdmn

It worked, I can now select each row and columns. But how can I select each row ("World 1", "World 2" and "World 3") and make it retrieve each value? For example, World 1 row will retrieve value "world_1", world 2 row will retrieve value "world_2", etc..

This code below didnt work for me
`<option id="world_1" value="world_1">
 World 1
</option>`

Comment: Did you try the code I posted?If you click it displays the values of each column.Is that not what you wanted?Can you exaplain how it should work?

Comment: I am trying to make a server list for my game. like http://gota.io/web/
Each time you connect to my game, you connect to localhost + port 443 (which is "World 1").
For instance, when you select "World 2" then you're supposed to switch to the other world, which is localhost + port 5422.

Look here:
http://prntscr.com/bobip1

Comment: Ok so the code I gave you let's you retrieve the row and each column that was clicked.Then just write an if statement to evaluate which world the user clicked on

Comment: How do I do that? I'm sorry but I'm not that experienced with coding

Comment: Just google "if statement in javascript" or better yet do a tutorial on javascript, here's an example - http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: Can you please help me with making an if statement? I don't know what to look for.. How should the code be?